# Oracle Goldengate - IF statement - Not equal

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

`@STREQ(INITIAL, 'F')` will return `TRUE` if `INITIAL` column has value `F`

I want to check cases where `INITIAL` <> `F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@IF` function.  For example:

```
@IF(@STREQ(INITIAL, 'F'), 0, 1)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/1212/gg-winux/GWURF/column_conversion_functions025.htm#GWURF815):

The following compares the value of the **region** column to the literal value **EAST**. If **region** = **EAST**, the record passes the filter.

```
FILTER (@STREQ (region, 'EAST'))
```

You could use `@STREQ` in a comparison to determine a result, as shown in the following example. If the state is **NY**, the expression returns **East Coast**. Otherwise, it returns **Other**.

```
@IF (@STREQ (state, 'NY'), 'East Coast', 'Other')
```